# Does Displaying in FullScreen diable 'rendering' of other windows in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Currently developing an APP using C++.
I am displaying multiple sub-windows in a single main window.
When one of the subwindows is put in Full Screen Mode , does the rendering of the other windows stop?

Answer (score 0):

> does the rendering of the other windows stop?

That depends on the implementation. If the program is implemented correctly, then the rendering should stop only if the window is fully covered.

Some people like to update the window in a timer callback (which is a bad practice), and then it would continue to render even when covered.

[glutDisplayFunc](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) is called only when there is a need to refresh the window.